# How do you generate rDoc for a particular plugin using rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rdoc

OK, I am trying to generate the rDoc for paperclip, but the rake task is choking on another plugin before it gets to it, so this is out of the question:

```
rake doc:plugins
```

I could go and fix up the broken plugin, but I'm busy and lazy, so I just want to generate the docs for paperclip. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unbelievably, I've just figured it out!

```
rake doc:plugins:paperclip
```

That was simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just run rdoc from the plugin's individual directory. This wouldn't include it in your project's /doc folder, but it would create a /doc folder inside the plugin which you can browse